# Does Azure Application Insights/Monitor have a way to check uptime of external REST APIs?

Tags: azure

with AI, you can ping websites from different regions, like pingdom.
However, we are looking for a way to call external (not hosted in Azure) rest endpoints, ideally being able to take the output of one, extract a token, then use it in the parameters of another.  This can be done with Synthetics in NewRelic (extremely expensive), or "advanced" checks in pingdom (doesn't support UK as a source), but we would prefer to do it via Azure.

We could setup a VM, and run curl from a shell script, but this is a poor solution.

This is not to be confused with using REST apis to access azure monitor, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Insights seems to support uptime checks.

See:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

I don't think it is sophisticated enough to allow for the use of the output of one request in the next.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself.